# Calling methods of fullcalendar 4 in angular 7+

Tags: angular, fullcalendar-4

I've created a calendar component using the Fullcalendar Angular docs.
When I try to call methods like addEvent, Rerender, refetch etc, its giving me this error :
`this.calendarComp.render is not a function`

Tried importing FullCalendarComponent of FullCalendar/angular, but this did not even contain the functions like rerenderEvents, addevents etc in fullcalendar.component.d.ts
Current Code is below:

CalendarComponent.ts

```
@ViewChild('calendar', { static: true }) calendarComp: Calendar; // the #calendar in the template
  ngOnInit() {
    // OPTIONS IN CALENDAR

    console.log(this.calendarComp)
    this.options = {
      businessHours: {
        daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        startTime: '00:00',
        endTime: '24:00',
      },
      editable: true,
      customButtons: { 
        test:{
          text:"click for Now",
          click: function(){
            this.calendarComp.getNow();  //Example function present in Main.d.ts of Fullcalendar/core
          }
        }
      },
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title test',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,listView,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, bootstrapPlugin, timeGrigPlugin],
      events: [
        {
          title: 'test', startRecur: new Date('2019-08-01'), allDay: false, startTime: '14:00:00', duration: '08:00', daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        constraint: 'businessHours', endRecur: new Date('2019-09-07'),
        overlap: true
        }
      ]
    };
```

html:

```
<full-calendar

  #calendar
  id="calendar"
  themeSystem="bootstrap"
  [businessHours]="options.businessHours"
  [editable]="true"
  [events]="options.events"
  [header]="options.header"
  [customButtons]="options.customButtons"
  [plugins]="options.plugins"
  (eventClick)="eventClick($event)"
  (addEventSource)="addEventSource($event)"
  (setProp)="setProp($event)"
  (rerenderEvents)="setProp($event)"
></full-calendar>
```

Im trying to call rerenderEvents when adding dynamic event, but Im unable to access this method itself.

```
this.calendarComp.rerenderEvents is not a function
```

Comment: `(rerenderEvents)="setProp($event)"` makes no sense there. rerenderEvents is a separate method to be called by itself. It's not an option you can pass to the calendar at setup time

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular shows you how to call methods correctly (in the section entitled "accessing fullCalendar's API)

Comment: rerenderEvents line was a typo my bad. And I tried this,
```let calendarApi= this.calendarComp.getApi();
    console.log(calendarApi.getDate());```
Error: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined```

Comment: Well it's supposed to work. Out of context, I can't tell if that code was used correctly in the right circumstances or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its late for an answer but it might help other as well.
 For Angular 8 and Full calendar version 4 Follow this syntax to resolve all issues related to this getApi() is undefined as mentioned in comment of OP

```js
//In typescript declare
@ViewChild('calendar', { static: true }) calendar: FullCalendarComponent;


ngOnInit() {
//For render issues in ionic/angular applications
setTimeout(function () {
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))

  }, 1)
}
 myFunc(){
 let calendarApi = this.calendar.getApi();
  calendarApi.render();

}
```

```html
<full-calendar #calendar 
    [defaultView]="defaultView" 
    schedulerLicenseKey='GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source'
      [plugins]="calendarPlugins" 
      [header]="header" 
      [duration]="duration" 
      [slotDuration]="slotDuration"
      [aspectRatio]="aspectRatio" 
      [views]="views" 
      [editable]="editable"
      [resourceLabelText]="resourceLabelText"
      [resources]="resources" 
      [events]="events" 
      [eventStartEditable]="eventStartEditable"
      [eventDurationEditable]="eventDurationEditable" 
      [dragRevertDuration]="dragRevertDuration"
      [customButtons]="customButtons" 
      [resourceAreaWidth]="resourceAreaWidth" 
      [slotLabelFormat]= "slotLabelFormat"
      deepChangeDetection="true"
      resourceGroupField= "building"
      (eventClick)="eventClick($event)"
      (dateClick)="dateClick($event)"
      

    ></full-calendar>
```

> Also check this github [issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular/issues/259#issuecomment-571079226)